# Show field dependent on whether other field contains data

Tags: sql

Is it possible in an SQL query to only show a field if another field has data?  For example, if Field1 <> '', then show the value in Field2 else don't show the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using a [case statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). (At least in SQL Server)

```
select case when Field1 <> '' 
            then Field2  
       end as Field2
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure (this works in Oracle and SQLite):

```
select 
  field1,
  (case 
     when field1 is null then null
     else field2
   end) field2_wrapped
from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

if 'has no data' means the empty string (''), you need to use this statement:

```
SELECT Filed2 FROM Table1 WHERE Filed1<>''
```

If 'no data' means NULL value, you need use

```
SELECT Filed2 FROM Table1 WHERE NOT (Filed2 IS NULL)
```

Comment: I'm not so sure. This might be what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Standard SQL functions `COALESCE()` and `NULLIF()`:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(Field1, ''), Field2)
```